# No such key “idle-delay” in org.gnome.desktop.screensaver

Tags: gnome-screensaver

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 with Unity desktop environment
I cannot stop my screen from shutting down via the Settings, so i tried it via command line.

But when executing the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-delay 0
```

I receive the following error:

```
No such key “idle-delay”
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `idle-dim` instead of `idle-delay`

You can accomplish your goal through a different setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```